How to speed up "Write Vector Tiles (MBTiles)"
I'm encountering a significant delay while exporting my map, which contains a large number of polygons, into a Vector Tiles MBTiles file. Currently, it seems to progress at only 50KB every 30 seconds!
Does anyone have suggestions on how to expedite this process?

QGIS version: 3.36.1-Maidenhead
QGIS code revision: 3e589453
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.18
GDAL version: 3.8.4
GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.3.1, December 1st, 2023
PDAL version: 2.6.0 (git-version: 3fced5)

Edit
Some more informations:

Operating System: Windows 10
Datasource: GeoJson File 200MB
Zoom: Level 0 - 12
Area: Germany


which operating system? where are you writing to? what is the data source? what zoom level are you using? how big an area are you converting?

Hi lan Turton, i added some more informations

Have you tried with some other format than GeoJSON? It does not support spatial indexing and therefore it may be that for every tile the whole 200 MB of data must be read.
